# Handle static passkey on ble characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an android app that connects with a BLE device. One of the characteristics has a static passkey set on it so if I try to write to it a dialog should pop up asking for the passkey(similar to the one that appears while bonding). How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean with "One of the characteristics has a static passkey set on it"? Do you mean you have set up security requirements, e.g. require an encrypted connection to write to it?

Comment: It means that it is encrypted. Requires authentication.